# Best approach to download a database to an iOS device

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sqlite, core-data

<sub>Yes, there are many questions on this topic here on SO, but I could not find a satisfying answer.</sub>

I'm working on a little project with some guys. The idea is to add some data to a database, which later can be used in an app. The database will only be read on the device (select statements), and never edited by the user.

Two of the guys are supposed to do the feeding of the database. I have made a webpage where they can log in, and add/update/delete data as they want to. The webpage is written in php, and the data is stored in a database using sqlite.

It should be possible to do search-as-you-type searches in the app.

The database will be updated every once in a while. When that happens I want to update the local database on the device, but only the parts that has changed. This is the preferred way, but it could be ok to just download the complete database. That depends on what size the database gets later.

I need some guidance on where to go next. Some important questions:

1. Is sqlite the best choice of database for this? I could change it to mysql without too much work, if that's preferred. Or is there another, better solution?
2. How do I save the data to the device, and how do I use it? Are there any good frameworks for this? I only need to do some simple select-statements on the device.
3. Should I use any of these in my solution?

   - Core Data: I'm not familiar with it yet, but it seems like it is a lot of work to use it. (?)
   - JSON/REST: Should I send data as JSON/REST? I've seen the [RESTkit](http://restkit.org/), but I haven't used it.
4. Is there anything else I should know about?

So.. What is the best approach here? I am not sure at all on what to do next. Some explanations and/or references to useful resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it depends. If data set is big i would go with CoreData. If it's small simple NSArray/NSDictionary will be easier. As for transfer, i would use simple PLIST or JSON. Everything depends on your needs and time you want to invest in your project.

Comment: I think the database will have about 1500-2000 records (max), but it will take some months to fill it up. What would you recommend? Sqlite or mysql?

Comment: i would recomend CoreData on iPhone

Answer (score 0):

1. On this item I think you are talking about the server database, correct me if I'm wrong. I would prefer using MySQL on server because it's more robust than SQLite.
2. You can use directly SQLite on device or use CoreData. On both ways you'll have an SQLite database on device. The difference will be the way you access it. To directly access SQLite you can use the SQLite C API (libsqlite3.0.dylib). The CoreData is also very good but it requires more time to learn than the SQLite C API.
3. It's very easy to use JSON to communicate to your web services. PHP has a very good JSON support and on device you could use the TouchJSON (https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON)
4. I don't know. :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out TouchJSON. One question: if I use mysql on the server, can I easily create a copy of it as a local sqlite database on the device? I just want to avoid using internet access for every query.

Comment: You can ship your App with the basic database (the sqlite file with structure and some initial data). Later you get the differences between databases with JSON and update the local database.

Comment: So.. SQLite on both web and device?

Comment: Just to make things clear: You have to create the same structure on server and on device. The difference will be the following: On server will be using MySQL and on device will be SQLite. You will fill the client database reading JSON data from your web service.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.  Is sqlite the best choice of database for this? I could change it to mysql without too much work, if that's preferred. Or is there another, better solution?
```

Yes Sqlite is better

```
1.  How do I save the data to the device, and how do I use it? Are there any good frameworks for this? I only need to do some simple select-statements on the device.
```

NSFileManager is What you need to use, First of all, you need to request for the sqlite database from the server, that will download the entire database to your documents folder in the App

```
1.  Should I use any of these in my solution?
•   Core Data: I'm not familiar with it yet, but it seems like it is a lot of work to use it. (?)
```

It is a little bit broader in conceptually, Though it uses sqlite, and you no need to add the data from the device to the database, that is not suggestable for you.

```
•   JSON/REST: Should I send data as JSON/REST? I've seen the RESTkit, but I haven't used it.
```

You can use JSON to download the data.

```
1.  Is there anything else I should know about?
```

The sqlite database you prepare in the server should be like having same table names and structure, so that your device queries can be executed,